# How to position lighting and remove shadows in ros3djs?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros3djs, markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I display markers using `ros3djs` they appear to be darker than they do on my default `RViz` setup. It seems my issue is related to lighting direction in `ros3djs` because I played around with different views in `RViz` and found that the same issues with shadowing there but from different directions. To me, it seems that I need to specify lighting direction in `ros3djs`. Is this possible?

***Markers on `ros3djs` web GUI:***

[image: image description]

***Markers on `RViz`:***

[image: image description]

I've played around with options like `alpha` and `intensity` in `ROS3D.Viewer` but these do not solve the problem. I'm hoping something like the pseudo code below might be available but I can't find anything on the docs [here](http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/ros3djs/current/ROS3D.Viewer.html)...... any ideas?

***Initial viewer setup (real code):***

```
let viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
    divID : 'map',
    width : 600,
    height : 600,
    background : '#FFFFFF',
    alpha : 1.0,
    antialias : true,
    intensity : 1.0,
    cameraPose : {x : -1, y : 0, z : 20},
    displayPanAndZoomFrame : true
});
```

***Some pseudo code that I hope someone can advise how to properly implement:***

```
viewer.addObject(new ROS3D.LightingPosition({x : -1, y : 0, z : 20}));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376724/how-to-position-lighting-and-remove-shadows-in-ros3djs?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-04-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-22**:
I would say it's actually RViz which is "wrong" here. It has a pretty limited lighting model IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some troubleshooting, it turns out that lighting direction was not the problem - it was the default ambient light colour. I therefore solved this problem by changing the colour of the ambient light to white using `three.js`. Here's my code snippet:

```
viewer.scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff));
```

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1